Issues with Establishing WebSocket Connection via JHipster, Spring Cloud Gateway, and Traefik
I'm experiencing difficulties in establishing a WebSocket connection through Spring Cloud Gateway and Traefik in my JHipster project. When I attempt to create a WebSocket connection, I encounter the following error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade cannot be cast to class reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse (org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade and reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerResponse are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

It seems that Spring Cloud Gateway is not correctly forwarding the WebSocket traffic to the target service.
Question:
Has anyone encountered similar issues and can provide guidance on how to resolve this problem? Are there any known workarounds or configuration changes I should make to successfully route WebSocket connections through Spring Cloud Gateway and Traefik? Or are there alternative approaches that might work better?
Setup:
JHipster Project: My project is generated using JHipster and utilizes Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Gateway.
Spring Cloud Gateway: I am using Spring Cloud Gateway to route requests to various microservices.
Traefik: Traefik is used as the ingress controller to route traffic to the correct services. It is also configured to support WebSocket connections.
Kubernetes: My entire application is running in a Kubernetes cluster.
Configuration:
Spring Cloud Gateway Configuration (application-prod.yml):
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: meinauto_route
          uri: lb://meinauto
          predicates:
            - Path=/meinauto/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
        - id: websocket_route
          uri: lb:ws://meinauto
          predicates:
            - Path=/meinwebsocket/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1

Service and Deployment Configuration in Kubernetes:
Service:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: meinauto
  namespace: consul-demo
spec:
  selector:
    app: meinauto
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8980
      targetPort: 8980

Deployment:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: meinauto
  name: meinauto
  namespace: consul-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: meinauto
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: meinauto
      annotations:
        consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject: "true"
        consul.hashicorp.com/service-tags: "traefik.enable=true,traefik.http.routers.meinauto.entrypoints=websecure,traefik.http.routers.meinauto.rule=Host(`meinauto.example.com`)"
        consul.hashicorp.com/service-check-http: "/management/health"
        consul.hashicorp.com/service-check-interval: "20s"
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: egeliizmir/meinauto:latest
        name: meinauto
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8980
          name: http
        env:
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONSUL_HOST
          value: "consul-server.consul"
        - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONSUL_PORT
          value: "8500"
        - name: CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR
          value: "http://consul-server.consul:8500"
        - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
          value: "prod"
        - name: CONSUL_HOST
          value: "consul-server.consul.svc.cluster.local"
        - name: CONSUL_PORT
          value: "8500"

WebSocketConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Value("${frontend.caller.host:http://meinauto.example.com:8980}")
  private String frontendCallerHost;

  @Autowired
  private final WebSocketTokenFilter webSocketTokenFilter;

  public WebSocketConfig(WebSocketTokenFilter webSocketTokenFilter) {
    this.webSocketTokenFilter = webSocketTokenFilter;
  }

  @Override
  public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(webSocketTokenFilter);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    RequestUpgradeStrategy upgradeStrategy = new TomcatRequestUpgradeStrategy();
     registry
    .addEndpoint("/meinwebsocket")
    .setHandshakeHandler(new DefaultHandshakeHandler(upgradeStrategy))
    .setAllowedOrigins("*");
}

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry
        .setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
        .enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
        .setTaskScheduler(heartBeatScheduler())
        .setHeartbeatValue(new long[] {10000L, 10000L});
  }

  @Bean
  public TaskScheduler heartBeatScheduler() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
  }    
}

meinauto.service.ts
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://meinauto.example.com:8980/meinwebsocket');

ws.onopen = () => {
  console.log('Connected to WebSocket server');
  ws.send(JSON.stringify({ token: `Bearer ${token}` }));
};

ws.onmessage = (event) => {
  const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
  this.messageSubject.next(message);
};

ws.onerror = (error) => {
  console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
};

ws.onclose = () => {
  console.log('WebSocket connection closed');
};

